# How to visualize the CGImage when extracting pixel data in swift

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, pixel, cgimage

I am getting the color of one pixel using the `getPixelColor` function below. However, I am unclear of which exact pixel is being accessed from the passed `CGPoint`. Where could I view the 'origin' of the `CGImage` as being? The upper-left? Lower-left? Neither really makes sense with the pixel colors I am getting with my images.

```
extension CGImage {
  func getPixelColor(pos: CGPoint) -> UIColor {

      let pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(self.CGImage))
      let data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)

      let pixelInfo: Int = ((Int(self.size.width) * Int(pos.y)) + Int(pos.x)) * 4

      let r = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo]) / CGFloat(255.0)
      let g = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+1]) / CGFloat(255.0)
      let b = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+2]) / CGFloat(255.0)
      let a = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+3]) / CGFloat(255.0)

      return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
  }
```

}

I think the confusion lies within the line:

`let pixelInfo: Int = ((Int(self.size.width) * Int(pos.y)) + Int(pos.x)) * 4`

I am unclear on how the data is accessed through this `Int` value.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

pixels are 32 bits, 4 bytes (RGBA in that order).  They are arranged in rows, one after the other.  To get the row of a pixel therefore you advance your pointer by row * rowWidthInBytes.  The rowWidthInBytes is just the width, times the numberOfBytesPerPixel (4).  To get the column you just add the yOffset * numberOfBytesPerPixel.  The equation looks like this:

```
pixelOffset = row * rowWidthInBytes + yOffset * numberOfBytesPerPixel
```

rearranging:

```
pixelOffset = row * (width * numberOfBytesPerPixel) + yOffset * numberOfBytesPerPixel
pixelOffset = (row * width + yOffset) * numberOfBytesPerPixel
pixelOffset = (width * row + yOffset) * numberOfBytesPerPixel
```

Change the names and ad some CGFloat to Int conversions and this is:

```
let pixelInfo: Int = ((Int(self.size.width) * Int(pos.y)) + Int(pos.x)) * 4
```

Comment: So in that line of code, would the position (0,0) correspond to the bottom left of an image?

Comment: depends on the orientation of the image, unfortunately.  for historical reasons Quartz uses the Mac OS coordinate system which is Cartesian.  In iOS positive Y points down, so its scaled by -Y or reflected about the x-axis.  This can sometimes cause your image to appear upside down when using the cgMethods.  UIImage knows its orientation and will rotate accordingly when drawing. https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimage/1624141-imageorientation